# updating error in JSP, eclipse

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

---

**- Can not issue data manipulation
   statements with executeQuery().**

---

***UPDATING JAVA CODE***

```
MultiDBManager db8=new MultiDBManager(uif);
String updateString = "UPDATE pklrsc SET pr_prod_rate="+rate+" , pr_ln_cst="+cost+" WHERE pr_rsc_cde= "+component+" ";
db8.execSQL(updateString);
```

***.java FILE CODE***

```
    public ResultSet execSQL(String sql) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("execSQL");
    return super.execSQL(processQuery(sql));
    }

private String processQuery(String sql){
System.out.println("processQuery");
return mdb.getCacheDB().procSQL(sql, false);
}
```

***ERROR MESSAGE***

```
value i: 1
component: ACODE0001
rate: 2.00
cost: 261.22
execSQL
processQuery
Execute = UPDATE c66_p30_BIS.pklrsc SET pr_prod_rate=2.00 , pr_ln_cst=261.22 WHERE pr_rsc_cde= ACODE0001 
Nov 4, 2010 4:54:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.checkForDml(Statement.java:398)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call `executeUpdate()` when using `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, rather than `executeQuery()`

Also note that using code in JSP, which is a view technology, is not encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a hidden `executeQuery` call to update values in the database. That's not allowed (see exception).

This method call actually causes your trouble:

```
mdb.getCacheDB().procSQL(sql, false);
```

Find an alternative to send update statements (Actually I don't know what API you're using here)